# Numpy: Conditional searchsorted

Tags: python, numpy, search

I have the following arrays

```
I0 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
X0 = np.array([1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

I1 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
X1 = np.array([1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

For the values in `X1` where `I1 == 1` I want to find the indices in `X0` where `(I0 == 1) & (X0 <= X1)`

```
indices = np.searchsorted(X0[I0 == 1], X1[I1 == 1], side='right')-1
X0[I0 == 1][indices] # [1, 5, 5, 8]
```

but rather than indices into `X0[I0 == 1]` I want indices into `X0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indices of the corresponding elements are

```
Q0 = np.arange(X0.size)[I0 == 0]
```

So

```
indices = Q0[indices]
```

On an unrelated note, I would highly recommend making your `I*` arrays boolean. For example:

```
I0 = np.array([True, False, False, False, True, False, False, True])
```

This will allow you to index with it directly without having to create another temp array:

```
X0[I0]
```

Comment: Not so unrelated I think because what you are suggesting only works if `I0` is boolean. Also, there are numpy functions for that (`where`, `nonzero`, `flatnonzero`)

Comment: @Paul. Updated. That was my mistake. Those functions make more temp arrays, which I'm suggesting OP can partially avoid